# Generics and Varargs - how to work with a subclass

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions

Consider the following interface :

```
public interface Addresses <T extends Number> {

    T[] getAddress();

    void setAddress(T...address);
}
```

The compiler accepts this implementation:

```
@Override
public Integer[] getAddress() {.........}

@Override 
public void setAddress(Number... address)  {.........} //some warning
```

But does not accept:

```
@Override 
public void setAddress(Integer... address)  {.........}
```

Why can't I override T varargs with Integer varargs, the same way I override T[] with Integer[] ?

How can I override `setaddress` so it accepts integers and keep the varargs flexibility ?

**Edit:** adding the two full classes :

```
public interface Addresses <T extends Number> {

    T[] getAddress();
    void setAddress(T...address);//warning: Type safety: Potential heap pollution 
}

public class Address implements Addresses{

    public Address() {}

    @Override
    public Integer[] getAddress() {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAddress(Integer... address) {
        // Error: The method setAddress(Integer...) of type Address must 
        //override or implement a supertype method
    }

    /*
    @Override
    public void setAddress(Number... address) {
        // No compiler errors   
    }
    */
}
```

**Edit:** is it a duplicate of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) ? 
 I don't think so. Maybe the information needed to answer my question is included in this post, but I don't think it is the same question.

Comment: Please show the full definition of the class including how you defined `T` for that class, and the exact warning instead of "some warning".

Comment: Trying to replicate your experiment shows the inverse result. The code compiles with `Integer...`, and doesn't compile with `Number...`. Post the whole code of the implementing class.

Comment: *"Maybe the information needed to answer my question is included in this post"* And that's what defines a dupe. You're here for over 2 years and should know that.

Comment: Questions that maybe answered by the same answer, are not necessarily the same questions. If duplicates are "question has been asked before ***AND*** already has an answer" than the question marked as duplicate isn't a duplicate. I agree with " There are similar questions, yes, and so-called “exact” duplicates do happen, but they are kind of rare in my experience." as stated in this post: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you did `class NumberAdresses implements Addresses<Number>{` (otherwise i can not reproduce your error).

So why is `Integer[]` valid as return type for `getAdresses()`; because you are generally allowed to use supertypes when overriding methods (Thats called covariant return types).

That is not allowed for parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what's wrong thanks to k5_ answer. Had to use

```
public class Address implements Addresses<**Integer**>
```